# Second combobox is populated depending on option from first combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

So I have two combobox's. The first combobox has all the states and the second would show the districts of the selected state. Note that the options are coming from a .txt file.

So in this case the "states.txt" file is formed like "state code;state".

Ex:

01;New York

02;New Jersey

...

The state combobox is working fine, below is the code used:

```
List<string> States = File.ReadAllLines("states.txt").ToList();

foreach(string Line in States)
{
     string[] state_element = Line.Split(';');
     combo_states.Items.Add(state_element[1]);
}
```

The problem now is having the second combobox show the districts of the selected state.

The "district.txt" file is formed like "state code; district code; district".

Ex:

01;01;Manhattan

01;02;Brooklyn

...

Also note that I am not using any form of database, so no SQL or anything, just c# language.

Comment: element[1] is not defined. you probably meant state_element[1]. I would suggest error checking to make sure state_element.length > 2

Comment: what is combo_states object?

Comment: combo_states would only appear the states in the txt file, so state_element[1]

Comment: @TyroneAndrews please have a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you are losing the Id of the state when you just put its name in the Combobox.

set your first combobox to display the 'Name' and have 'Id' as value:

```
combo_states.ValueMember = "Id";
combo_states.DisplayMember = "Name";

foreach(string Line in States)
{
     string[] state_element = Line.Split(';');
     combo_states.Items.Add(new { Id = state_element [0], Name = state_element[1]});
}
```

Now in your combobox's on SelectedValueChange event you can access the Id of the state like:

```
string id = combo_states.SelectedValue;
```

and having districts like:

```
var districts = File.ReadAllLines("district.txt")
.Select(x => 
     { 
         string split = x.Split(';');
         return new {StateId = split[0], DistrictId = split[1], DistrictName = split[1]}
     };
```

Then:

```
string id = combo_states.SelectedValue;
district_combo.ValueMember = "DistrictId";
district_combo.DisplayMember = "DistrictName";
foreach(var item in districts.Where(d => d.StateId == id))
{
      district_combo.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: It Worked! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a load button to load the districts from district.txt file.
 For example :

// in load_button click event

```
    List<string> districts = File.ReadAllLines("district.txt").ToList();
    foreach(string Line in districts)
    {
        string[] district_element = Line.Split(';');
        if(district_element[0] == combo_states.Text)
        combo_districts.Items.Add(district_element[2]);
    }
```

Hope this will work.