# two values in DataValueField?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, linq

how can i add two value into datavaluefield of a dropdownlist (orderid, vendorid). when selected a vendor information will be displayed with the vendorid then gridview will grab the orderid and list all order details. what other ways can i do this?

Comment: I just answered a similar question 2 hours ago, please see it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166011/second-combobox-is-populated-depending-on-option-from-first-combobox/59166133#59166133)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166011/second-combobox-is-populated-depending-on-option-from-first-combobox/59166133#59166133]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

One way you might consider is storing just the OrderId field in the DataValueField. Then when this changes, you can look up the Order for the OrderId and find the VendorId and use this to find the Vendor and populate the vendor information. This will work if the Order has the Vendor Id associated with it.